# Quickblox: Accessing remote audio data: QBRTCAudioTrackSinkInterface delegate methods not called

Tags: ios, quickblox

I am starting to integrate Quickblox for my application especially for Video chat. And I want to get the remote streaming audio data. I want to process that audio data. So I got to know it is possible in Quickblox. In their dev doc they said, we have to use **QBRTCAudioTrackSinkInterface** for this feature. I did what they mentioned in the document

```
QBUUser *user = [self.usersDatasource userWithID:uID.integerValue];
if (!user) {
  user = [QBUUser user];
  user.ID = uID.integerValue;
  QBRTCAudioTrack *audioTrack=[self.session remoteAudioTrackWithUserID:@(user.ID)];
  [audioTrack addSink:self];
}
```

But the delegate methods are not called. I have used the https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-ios-sdk/ - sample-videochat-webrtc.

Please provide me the best way to do that,

Comment: Have you got any success? i am finding the same...